# Wordpress custom post type & taxonomy rewrite problem

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, taxonomy, custom-post-type

I have a problem with URL rewrite with cutom post type & taxonomies.

Here is my actual code http://pastebin.com/Q8USd2Tv (I removed stuff like labels etc.)

I want my link to be like this:

Overview page: /base/ 
Taxonomy: /base/taxonomy-name
Detail page: /base/taxonomy-name/single-name

Can you please help me with this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your answer is a plugin of mine, [Taxonomic SEO Permalink](http://rakesh.tembhurne.com/projects/taxonomic-seo-permalinks/). Currently WordPress supports taxonomies but one is not able to use custom taxonomy in permalink structure by default. So I created this plugin that helped me in having custom taxonomy in URLs.

This plugins helps behave custom taxonomy similar to categories. Recently I added feature that supports sub-taxonomies in url. It's not that perfect but it solves the problem to some extent.